# Get Form Input via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid plugin which I call via Ajax. I have index.php and a getGridData.php. How will I pass form input in getGridData.php via ajax and use it in getGridData.php? I tried serialize but I can't pass or access it on getGridData.php. I need it as parameters for mysql. Here's my code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function jgGrid()
{
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "inc/Controller/getGridData.php"+$("#thisForm").serialize(),
        data : formData,
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        colNames: ["SiteID", "TerminalID", "TransactionType", "Amount", "ServiceStatus"],
        colModel: [
        { name: "SiteID"},
        { name: "TerminalID"},
        { name: "TransactionType"},
        { name: "Amount"},
        { name: "ServiceStatus"},
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10,20],
        sortname: "SiteID",
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: 'auto',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: ""
        });     
    });
}
</script>
```

getGridData.php

```
include('../Model/Queries.php');

$cardnumber =       $_POST['cardnumber'];
$transact_type =    $_POST['transact_type'];
$fromdate =         $_POST['fromdate'];
$todate =           $_POST['todate'];

$loyalty = new Queries();

$get_mid =  $loyalty->loyaltyConn($cardnumber);
$somedata = json_encode($loyalty->nposConn($get_mid, $transact_type, $fromdate, $todate));

echo $somedata;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the data using `url: "url"+$("#thisForm").serialize()` to `GET` variable but retrieving from `POST` so you need to change these:

```
$cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
// ...
$todate = $_POST['todate'];
```

To something like this:

```
$cardnumber = $_GET['cardnumber'];
// ...
$todate = $_GET['todate'];
```

Change all of them to `GET` Check the [examples here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Comment: Should I also change   mtype: "POST", to   mtype: "GET", in my script?

Comment: Yes you should, i missed it :-)